# Bouncing a ball from circular boundary

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, vector

[image]

This is the formula I found out :

*r = v − [2 (n · v) n]*

This is how I applied

```
    //Calculating normal
    nx = 350 -  SmileyReds[i].xpos ;
    ny = 350 -  SmileyReds[i].ypos ;

  //new calc
   v_newx = SmileyReds[i].xspeed - (2 *( nx * SmileyReds[i].xspeed + ny * SmileyReds[i].yspeed ) ) * nx;
   v_newy = SmileyReds[i].yspeed - (2 *( nx * SmileyReds[i].xspeed + ny * SmileyReds[i].yspeed ) ) * ny;

   SmileyReds[i].xspeed = v_newx;
   SmileyReds[i].yspeed = v_newy;
```

But instead of bouncing, the balls disappear when they hit the boundary:

Full src and preview http://jsfiddle.net/gj4Q7/4/

Thank you for your time, any tips are welcome!

Comment: I haven't fixed it all, but I have fixed a few things http://jsfiddle.net/gj4Q7/3/ Why so many loops btw? I have removed most of them.

Comment: @plalx thank you very much, I know the loops are not necessary, but I was going to combine them in the end when the bouncing worked properly, in your version the red smileys are going out of the circle :( do you know why?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "fixed a few things". Perhaps if you tell me where you found the formula and where it's explained I could help.

Comment: @plalx here : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33384/how-to-bounce-a-2d-point-particle-off-of-a-circular-edge and I found mistake and updated the fiddle but still the smileys are sticking to the circle boundary after some time and leaving the circle ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to normalize the normal :)

After

```
//Calculating normal
nx = 350 -  SmileyReds[i].xpos;
ny = 350 -  SmileyReds[i].ypos;
```

insert

```
var len = Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny);
nx = nx / len;
ny = ny / len;
```

You can see that you can otherwise easily get values in the range of 350*350 for the speed, catapulting your objects into space...

Comment: Yes I also found it out later, now the problem is as you can see on the updated fiddle, why are the red smileys sticking to the circle boundary after some time, is this the way it should work? When I change the tab I see the smileys out of the circle as well...